# Error Loading User form when database is blank

Tags: sql, vba

The database table is blank and I have coded the VBA User Form to load the Customer and User list at Userform_Initialize from the database table.

Now I am getting the EOF_BOF error which is fine since there is no data in the table. And I have to close the user form.

What should I do so that I dont receive an error while database is blank.

Below is the code.

```
Sql = "Select DISTINCT [Exec] from tblKPI"
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Open Sql, conn, adOpenStatic
rs.Movefirst
    With frmReport.lstUser
    .Clear
    Do
        .AddItem rs![exec]
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop Until rs.EOF
End With


'update Customers
Sql = "Select DISTINCT Customer from tblKPI"
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Open Sql, conn, adOpenStatic
rs.Movefirst
    With frmReport.Customer
    .Clear
    Do
        .AddItem rs![Customer]
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop Until rs.EOF
End With
```

Comment: You might want to `While Not rs.EOF` instead of `Loop Until`.  Sorry, test for `EOF` needs to happen before `.MoveFirst` per MSDN.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks Guyz, it worked !!!!!1

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:  Add `"IF NOT rs.EOF"` before each `rs.MoveFirst`.